# Auto-resolve all red-underlines in XML Layout file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, layout

I'm downgrading approximately 125 layout resources files, i.e.

```
activity_main.xml (v21)
activity_main.xml (v21-large)
activity_main.xml (v21-xlarge)
activity_main.xml (v21-small)
activity_main.xml (v21-xlarge-land)
```

...to:

```
activity_main.xml
activity_main.xml (large)
activity_main.xml (xlarge)
activity_main.xml (small)
activity_main.xml (xlarge-land)
```

The API-non-specified layout files throw some red underlines with suggestions. For example:

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
```

...suggest adding:

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
```

I typically Alt-Enter through all of them manually to generate the changes.

Is there an automatic way to resolve all the red-underlines with one click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is partially possible.

In Android Sudio use Analyse -> Inspect Code

You get a list of all problems warnings etc.

The warnings/errors are sorted in categories. If they are solvable without additional user input, you can right click on a warning type and there will be a light bumlb to fix it for all problems of this type.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Enable auto import in android studio it will overcome max Alt-Enter problem**

For Windows/Linux, you can go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Java and make the following changes:
[image]

change Insert imports on paste value to All
markAdd unambigious imports on the fly option as checked
On a Mac, do the same thing in Android Studio -> Preferences

After this, all unambiguous imports will be added automatically.